# sum every 7 rows from column sales while ints representing n days away from installation of promotion-material (before and after the installation)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

2 Stores, each with its sales data per day. Both get equipped with promotion material but not at the same day. After the pr_day the promotion material will stay there. Meaning, there should be a sales boost from the day of the installation of the promotion material.

```
Installation Date:
Store A    -    05/15/2019
Store B    -    05/17/2019
```

To see if the promotion was a success we measure the sales before the pr-date and after by returning number of sales (not revenue but pieces sold) next to the int, indicating how far away it was from the pr-day: (sum of sales from both stores)

```
pr_date|    sales
-28    |    35
-27    |    40
-26    |    21
-25    |    36
-24    |    29
-23    |    36
-22    |    43
-21    |    31
-20    |    32
-19    |    21
-18    |    17
-17    |    34
-16    |    34
-15    |    37
-14    |    32
-13    |    29
-12    |    25
-11    |    45
-10    |    43
-9     |    26
-8     |    27
-7     |    33
-6     |    36
-5     |    17
-4     |    34
-3     |    33
-2     |    21
-1     |    28
1      |    16
2      |    6
3      |    16
4      |    29
5      |    32
6      |    30
7      |    30
8      |    30
9      |    17
10     |    12
11     |    35
12     |    30
13     |    15
14     |    28
15     |    14
16     |    16
17     |    13
18     |    27
19     |    22
20     |    34
21     |    33
22     |    22
23     |    13
24     |    35
25     |    28
26     |    19
27     |    17
28     |    29
```

you may noticed, that i already removed the day from the installation of the promotion material.

The issue starts with the different installation date of the pr-material. If I group by weekday it will combine the sales from different days away from the installation. It will just start at whatever weekday i define:

```
Select DATEDIFF(wk, change_date, sales_date), sum(sales)
from tbl_sales
group by DATEDIFF(wk, change_date, sales_date)

result:
    week | sales
    -4   | 75
    -3   | 228
    -2   | 204
    -1   | 235
    0    | 149
    1    | 173
    2    | 151
    3    | 167
    4    | 141
```

the numbers are not from the right days and there is one week to many. Guess this is comming from sql grouping the sales starting from Sunday and because the pr_dates are different it generates more than just the 8 weeks (4 before, 4 after)

trying to find a sustainable solution i couldn't find the right fit and decided to post it here. Very thankfull for every thoughts of the community about this topics. Quite sure there is a smart solution for this problem cause it doesn't look like a rare request to me

I tried it with over as well but i don't see how to sum the 7 days together as they are not date days anymore but delta to the pr-date

```
Desired Result:
week | sales
-4   | 240
-3   | 206
-2   | 227
-1   | 202
1    | 159
2    | 167
3    | 159
4    | 163
```

Attachment from my analysis by hand what the Results should be:

[image]

Why do i need the weekly summary -> the Stores are performing differently depending on the weekday. With summing 7 days together I make sure we don't compare mondays to sundays and so on. Furthermore, the result will be represented in a Line- or Barchart where you could see the weekday variation in a ugly way. Meaning it will be hard for your eyes to see the trend/devolopment of the salesnumbers. Whereas the weekly comparison will absorb this variations.

If anything is unclear please feel free to let me know so i could provide you with futher details

Thank you very much

Additional the different Installation date overview:
[image]

```
Shop A:
store A     
delta   date    sales
-28 17.04.2019  20
-27 18.04.2019  20
-26 19.04.2019  13
-25 20.04.2019  25
-24 21.04.2019  16
-23 22.04.2019  20
-22 23.04.2019  26
-21 24.04.2019  15
-20 25.04.2019  20
-19 26.04.2019  13
-18 27.04.2019  13
-17 28.04.2019  20
-16 29.04.2019  21
-15 30.04.2019  20
-14 01.05.2019  17
-13 02.05.2019  13
-12 03.05.2019  9
-11 04.05.2019  34
-10 05.05.2019  28
-9  06.05.2019  19
-8  07.05.2019  14
-7  08.05.2019  23
-6  09.05.2019  18
-5  10.05.2019  9
-4  11.05.2019  22
-3  12.05.2019  17
-2  13.05.2019  14
-1  14.05.2019  19
0   15.05.2019  11
1   16.05.2019  0
2   17.05.2019  0
3   18.05.2019  1
4   19.05.2019  19
5   20.05.2019  18
6   21.05.2019  14
7   22.05.2019  11
8   23.05.2019  12
9   24.05.2019  8
10  25.05.2019  7
11  26.05.2019  19
12  27.05.2019  15
13  28.05.2019  15
14  29.05.2019  11
15  30.05.2019  5
16  31.05.2019  8
17  01.06.2019  10
18  02.06.2019  19
19  03.06.2019  14
20  04.06.2019  21
21  05.06.2019  22
22  06.06.2019  7
23  07.06.2019  6
24  08.06.2019  23
25  09.06.2019  17
26  10.06.2019  9
27  11.06.2019  8
28  12.06.2019  23

Shop B:
store B     
delta   date    sales


-28 19.04.2019  15
-27 20.04.2019  20
-26 21.04.2019  8
-25 22.04.2019  11
-24 23.04.2019  13
-23 24.04.2019  16
-22 25.04.2019  17
-21 26.04.2019  16
-20 27.04.2019  12
-19 28.04.2019  8
-18 29.04.2019  4
-17 30.04.2019  14
-16 01.05.2019  13
-15 02.05.2019  17
-14 03.05.2019  15
-13 04.05.2019  16
-12 05.05.2019  16
-11 06.05.2019  11
-10 07.05.2019  15
-9  08.05.2019  7
-8  09.05.2019  13
-7  10.05.2019  10
-6  11.05.2019  18
-5  12.05.2019  8
-4  13.05.2019  12
-3  14.05.2019  16
-2  15.05.2019  7
-1  16.05.2019  9
0   17.05.2019  9
1   18.05.2019  16
2   19.05.2019  6
3   20.05.2019  15
4   21.05.2019  10
5   22.05.2019  14
6   23.05.2019  16
7   24.05.2019  19
8   25.05.2019  18
9   26.05.2019  9
10  27.05.2019  5
11  28.05.2019  16
12  29.05.2019  15
13  30.05.2019  17
14  31.05.2019  9
15  01.06.2019  8
16  02.06.2019  3
17  03.06.2019  8
18  04.06.2019  8
19  05.06.2019  13
20  06.06.2019  11
21  07.06.2019  15
22  08.06.2019  7
23  09.06.2019  12
24  10.06.2019  11
25  11.06.2019  10
26  12.06.2019  9
27  13.06.2019  6
28  14.06.2019  9
```

Comment: You data doesn't match requests e.g. `Select sum(sales)
from ..` can't produce 2 columns. Please provide an example with consistent table definitions, requests and data.

Comment: Please don't use images. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex What  is not clear for me, it's the rule how to match data for 2 stores. For a week we'll have more then 7 values of delta, but your hand analysys shows exactly 7 rows.

Comment: @Serg, is there any way to convert the excel table into html so one could still read it? i tried 2 converter (webapplications) but the result looked horrible so i decided to take the screenshot. The pictures are more explanatory than part of the question because all the numbers are in the code tables i made manually. 2 table with all single days-delta sales from both stores together and 3 table with the format in which i'm trying to get the results. I aded the last table as table of store A and B sepparatly for you. i hope i can clarify your request by that

Comment: Looks like you need just ignore calendar weeks and use `(delta +-1)/7` as week number.

Comment: @Serg the rule of combination i'm trying to get is sum the 7 days before the installation and return the result and this should be done for several shops where the installation date is different. That's why i started to work with the delta to installation date, s i can combine the weeks from different shops with different installation dates and see the effect of the promotion material. Thats why there are always 7 rows for each week. This 7 day represents exactly 7 days before the installation or after no matter which weekday the shop was changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
select wk, sum(sales) 
from (
    select 
         isnull(sa.sales,0) + isnull(sb.sales,0) sales
       , isnull(sa.delta , sb.delta) delta
       , case when isnull(sa.delta , sb.delta) = 0 then 0 
                  else case when isnull(sa.delta , sb.delta) > 0 then (isnull(sa.delta , sb.delta) -1) /7 +1
                            else (isnull(sa.delta , sb.delta) +1) /7 -1
                       end
             end wk
    from shopA  sa
    full join  shopB sb on sa.delta=sb.delta 
    ) t
group by wk;
```

[sql fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=803a110c300a0f728acd764986617ec9)

A more readable version, it doesn't run faster, just using CROSS APLLY  this way allows to indroduce sort of intermediate variables for cleaner code.

```
select wk, sum(sales) 
from (
    select 
         isnull(sa.sales,0) + isnull(sb.sales,0) sales
       , dlt delta
       , case when dlt = 0 then 0 
                  else case when dlt > 0 then (dlt - 1) / 7 + 1
                            else (dlt + 1) / 7 - 1
                       end
             end wk
    from shopA sa
    full join shopB sb on sa.delta=sb.delta
    cross apply (
      select dlt = isnull(sa.delta, sb.delta)
    ) tmp
) t
group by wk;
```

Finally, if you already have a query which produces a dataset with the `(pr_date, sales)` columns

```
select wk, sum(sales) 
from (
      select sales
        , case when pr_date = 0 then 0 
                  else case when pr_date > 0 then (pr_date - 1) / 7 + 1
                            else (pr_date + 1) / 7 - 1
                       end
             end wk
      from (
           -- ... you query here ... 
           )pr_date_sales
    ) t
group by wk;
```

Comment: holy cow, that seems to be way more difficult than i tought it would. how can you select wk when there is no declaration of what it actually is? or is this set by the wk after the end? like one could define a table name t1? I actually have one table with alle the sales instead of one for each shop. I take a few minutes to try to understand this solution and how it could be changed to fit my needs. thank you very much so far

Comment: `wk` is introduced in the inner `select`. See more readable version

Comment: i could implement your solution so it gives me the column wk with the right value in it but it throws an error on the group by wk line -> invalid column name

Comment: Are you sure? See the fiddle, it runs ok.

Comment: Your solution works fine, thats right. but i had to implement it into my sql query where i have only one table for all sells from different stores. so i made a nested select where i put your code and made a from (my generated table with my sql statements which gives the last table from my question) and then at the end tried to group by it but it gives me the error invalid column name. Must be some stupid beginner issue but i don't get where i made it. i actually make a select ..,...,.. from () t10 group by wk

Comment: if you already have a query which produces a dataset with the (pr_date, sales) .. see update.

Comment: @JDoe, that's actually a pretty simple query for this sort of thing. I could only additionally suggest that you can convert the delta into your week number with the following one-liner: `(((delta - SIGN(delta)) / 7) + SIGN(delta)) AS wk`, which is a little snappier than the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to take the day difference and use arithmetic.  Using `datediff()` with `week` counts week-boundaries -- which is not what you want.  That is, it normalizes the weeks to calendar weeks.

You want to leave out the day of the promotion, which makes this a wee bit more complicated.

I think this is the logic:

```
Select v.week_diff, sum(sales)
from tbl_sales s cross join
     (values (case when change_date < sales_date
                   then (datediff(day, change_date, sales_date) + 1) / 7
                   else (datediff(day, change_date, sales_date) - 1) / 7
              end)
     ) v(week_diff)
where change_date <> sales_date
group by v.week_diff;
```

There might be an off-by-one problem, depending on what you really want to do when the dates are the same.